# Install Java 1.7 on Knoppix

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, pydev

I am attempting to upgrade 32 bit Knoppix Java to run Java 1.7 so I can use PyDev with Eclipse 3.8 and run compilers which are common to security debug. Java install has always been a bit confusing to me even when following what appear to be logical steps. I cannot 'apt-get' openjdk java as the package is current as of 1.6 in the repository. So... I've downloaded Java 1.7 (32 bit) to install, but after rendering a machine useless in the past I am seeking guidence first.

My knoppix shows: 
    knoppix@Microknoppix:~/Downloads$ java -version
    java version "1.6.0_27"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-1)
    OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)

I do not know if I should be trying to search harder for an open jdk which is not pre-built or installing the Java 1.7.0_75 which I have downloaded and unziped/untared. Here is the version of knoppix.

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ uname -a
Linux Microknoppix 3.9.6 #25 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jun 15 15:27:01 CEST 2013 
i686 GNU/Linux
```

This is all following another stack overflow question showing the requirements for PyDev were 1.7 to see PyDev in the prefs of Eclipse. Specifically what are the steps to switch to Java 1.7 without messing up my OS? The Java is a 32 bit version. Thanks for reading/inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Steps derived from [Installing Oracle JRE on Debian or Ubuntu Systems](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installJreDeb.html) from datastax. First, make a directory to install the jvm (for example "/usr/lib/jvm")

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
```

Then download "jre-7u75-linux-i586.tar.gz" from Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html)

```
$ sudo tar zxvf jre-7u75-linux-i586.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm
```

Next run `update-alternatives --install` to set-up the java executable

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" \
        "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_75/bin/java" 1
```

Finally you can set that to your default JRE like

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_75/bin/java
```